# Do you infect the city you are scoring?

Tags: pandemic-contagion

One of the cities has the ability:

> Play immediately: Draw one card for each city you are infecting.

Do you draw a card for that city?

Comment: I believe the answer is no. Is there any confirmation of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you do not.

The designer has confirmed this [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1281279/city-card-timing).

> *There are a few city cards which are play immediately and refer to the number of cities you currently infect. Does that include the current city card you are in the middle of resolving? or just all the other city cards where you have cubes?*
>
> > For question one: it does not include the current city card you are resolving. It has been eradicated, so no longer among the living.